# Is there an advantage of the new HTML5 elements?

Tags: html

HTML5 introduces some nice new elements, `<canvas>`, `<audio>`, and `<video>`, that will be useful in web design.

What I don't se is the point of the new `<section>`, `<header>`, `<nav>`, and so on.

I can see a use if you're a very small web designer, in that they might have user agent stylesheet CSS rules (A bit like `<blockquote>` is similar to `<div>`, just has margins as well.)

However, if you're designing a bigger site, you will probably have you're own CSS rules for things like these, so there won't be any benefit.

So s there any real advantage of using these elements?

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is *Semanticity.*  `<section>`, `<header>`, and `<nav>` are more fitting semantically and easier to parse for machines than `<div>`, `<div>`, and `<ul>`. See e.g. point 3 in [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/essentials-modern-web-design/)

Comment: I honestly don't see the difference between very small websites and bigger sites, the way you distinguish them. Sorry. And `blockquote` is NOT the same as a `div` with margins.

Comment: As everyone has said, it's all down to semantics. These are going to be increasingly important in future... just consider Facebook's Open Graph implementation (or Dublin Core) to get an idea of why the semantic web is important.

Comment: @MrLister What I'm saying is that if your in charge of Stack Overflow's stylesheets, you will have you're own rules for pretty much everthing. But If you're me, who has just a little site to play around with, you don't have CSS rules for everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recent [statement](http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2012-February/034831.html) from Hixie, the HTML5 editor, says: “The use case for most of the ‘semantic’ markup is [just] easier authoring and maintenance, in particular for se­lec­tors in CSS.”

When authors use tags in certain ways, the markup is easier to read and modify to coworkers or others who work on the same markup. It is not realistic to expect (though admittedly possible) that browsers will do anything special with these elements (except render them as blocks and not inline elements) or that search engines will get enthusiastic about them.

Comment: I disagree agree about search engines, I'd very much expect them to be significant in future (the semantic web). Google already does things like handle parsing certain HTML elements (e.g. previews of tables, looks at lists for site structure / navigation cues).

Comment: Google does many things – heuristically. There is little hard evidence published on what it actually does with markup, but generally it deduces from the content instead of relying on markup. Statements about Google doing something with the new HTML5 elements are speculative and not very convincing.

Comment: It's not speculative. You can see this in the formatting of results. I've seen this on several sites of my own - with both tables (where tables are presented previewed in a tabular fashion) and with site structure from lists. It happens on sites I've made so I know there is no additional metadata it's using.

Comment: I'd add these are used by screen readers - like Jaws and VoiceOver - too. It's not at all just about easier authoring and maintenance.

Answer (score 7):

The advantage is mainly semantic. It's somewhat easier to maintain the code, and web crawlers can more easily determine where certain information is in the page.