# HTML5 new elements for structure vs <div>?

Tags: css, html

I saw a recent tutorial on HTML5 where the person only used the new structure elements from HTML5 such as `<header>`, `<section>`, `<aside>` and `<footer>` as opposed to `<div>` and the author mentioned that `<div>`'s clutter up the page and make the code less readable, however I'm wondering what other advantages or disadvantages do these HTML5 elements have if there are any?  - I know IE8 doesn't support them and he showed a workaround for it

Comment: You may find this relevent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340627/is-there-an-advantage-of-the-new-html5-elements?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

[Search Results of Advantages and disadvantages of html5](http://www.informationaboutnewtechnology.in/2012/06/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-html5.html)

Advantages:-

- Mutuality
- Cleaner markup / Improved Code
- Improved Semantics
- Elegant form
- Consistency
- Improved Accessibility
- Fulfill the need of Web application
- Offline Application cache
- Client-side database
- Geolocation

Disadvantages:-

- Browser Support
- The Language is a Spec